# How to pass state data from a client to a server component in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, xml, next.js

I am trying to simply read and write a locally stored .xml file with couple of <user> tags using TypeScript and NextJS.

I have three main components in three separate files:

1.  componet UserTable which shows the <user> info from .xml and is mainly responsible for displaying some data.

2. component AddUserForm which is responsible for inputting new user data and this data is stored in a useState variable named formValues. (this is a client component)

3. component AddNewUser which queries the .xml file with dummy data as of now. (this is a default server component)

I would like to pass the formValues from AddUserForm to AddNewUser component so that I can add the new <user> to the .xml with the inputted data instead of the dummy data.

I have understood it is quite complicated to pass state or in fact data in general from a client component to a server component.

I have tried multiple approaches like passing the formValues via useRouter and using SSR but everything seems a bit too complicated for the task and I am still unable to complete it.

*AddUserForm component*

```
'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from 'react';

const AddUserForm = () => {

  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    phone: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [id]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <label> Name </label>
            <input
                id="name"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={formValues.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label> Phone </label>
            <input
                id="phone"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Phone"
                value={formValues.phone}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </div>

        <div>
          <Link href="/">
            <button>
              Go Back
            </button>
          </Link>
          
          <button type="submit">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddUserForm;
```

*AddNewUser component*

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { parseString, Builder  } from 'xml2js';

const AddNewUser = (props: any) => {
    const xmlFilePath = './public/user.xml';
    const xmlContent = fs.readFileSync(xmlFilePath, 'utf-8');
   
    parseString(xmlContent, { explicitArray: false }, (error: any, result: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing user.xml:', error);
        } else {
    
          const newUser = {
            $: {
              name: 'New User',
              phone: '123456789'
            },
          };
      
          result.root.users.user.push(newUser);
      
          // Converting updated XML object to XML string
          const builder = new Builder();
          const updatedXmlContent = builder.buildObject(result);
        
          // Updating the new XML content back to the file
          fs.writeFileSync(xmlFilePath, updatedXmlContent);
        }
      });      

    return (
      <div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default AddNewUser
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from a client component (like AddUserForm) to a server (like AddNewUser) in Next.js, you can use API routes. API routes allow you to create server-side endpoints within your Next.js application, making it easy to handle data processing and manipulation on the server side

With NextJs13:

Craete API route:

`app/addnewuser/route.ts`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const { formValues } = request.body; // Assuming you're sending the data as JSON
    // Here, you can process the 'formValues' data and add it to the .xml file

    // console to demonstrate the data receiving on the server
    console.log(formValues);

    // Return a response
    NextResponse.status(200).json({ message: 'User added successfully' });
}
```

`In AddUserForm component add:`

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/addnewuser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ formValues }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Handle success
        console.log('User added successfully');
        // Optionally, you can reset the formValues state here
        setFormValues({ name: '', email: '' });
      } else {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error adding user');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for sharing the solution.

I have updated my question and added the code for better understanding.

Comment: I think you should change your logic, send the data to the backend, edit the xml file. Note*: you can also provide xml file via API routes.
I guess in your case you can use AddNewUser to just display the data.
Otherwise use AddUserForm also for editing the file. @Ishaan_B

Comment: I agree, I realised it as well. I should be having a back end server for handling .xml queries.

Comment: @Ishaan_B Note* you don't need seperate backend, you can use nextjs as backend with API routes

Comment: Got it! I haven't had much experience with Next.js' backend but I'll have a look. Thanks!